# Random UV angles

Tags: materials, uv, video, uv-image-editor

[image]

just wondered if anyone can help?

When I assign a video to multiple faces, it doesn't always have the same rotation. There are hundreds of them as the object is a giant spiral so can't go round manually adjusting. I'm wondering if there's some kind of sub-text-information that tell the uv editor which way the image should be but surely that should then be the same for every face? Maybe because it's a circle, the image angle changes in relation to the direction of the face?

Any potential solutions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do all faces show the same normal orientation? And how have you unwrapped?

Comment: hi Robin, the faces show different orientations as per the image. I just did a regular (not live) unwrap..